# Problem while calling "ShoppingCartInfo"

Tags: magento-1.7, soap-api-v2

I am getting error while calling "shoppingCartInfo" magento api

`SoapFault - faultcode: 'SOAP-ENV:Server' faultstring: 'Call to a member function setFinalPrice() on a non-object' faultactor: 'null' detail: null`. Please let me know in which it occurs.

Comment: Put more details. As far as I can see in XML shoppingCartInfoRequest have 3 params (sessionId, quoteId, storeId). It response entity. Check existing such quote in database, if you have access

Comment: getting this error after adding multiple products to the cart using API shoppingCartProductAdd; The response of shoppingCartProductAdd is true but after this call whenever I am calling shoppingCartInfo its reporting this error.

Comment: After adding product try to check this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.list.html . Does your quote exists in database? $proxy->shoppingCartInfo($sessionId, '15'); (In this example quote with id=15 should be in sales_flat_quote)